# Get the current sprint programmatically in Azure Devops

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops

I am trying to get the current sprint in AzureDevops so that I can create a new work item within the current sprint.

I tried making an [Iterations - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/iterations/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) API call with this URL:

`https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/{{team}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?$timeframe=current&api-version=5.1`

But it returns a Status code: 203 with content which is not useful.

However when I directly hit the URL in the browser I get a a 200 OK with proper Json object which has all the information I need.

[image]
This is my Code:

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 Uri url = new Uri("https://abcd.visualstudio.com/myproject/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?$timeframe=current&api-version=5.1");
 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
 var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Can someone tell me if I am missing something here?

Comment: `content which is not useful.` - what's the content?

Comment: Also, do you have any authentication code?

Comment: Hi I dont see a PAT token in the snippet above (maybe it is not listed for security) but it is required to access most of restapi call. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/rest/samples?view=azure-devops